# Bulk convert different types of videos with FFmpeg in one command line?

Tags: batch-file

i am trying for quite some time now, to be able to convert several video files AT ONCE in ffmpeg command line IN WINDOWS,
so far i managed to find this:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %a in ('dir /B *.wmv') do ffmpeg -i "%a.wmv" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p "%a.mp4"
```

which is great!
but... what if i want to convert entire dir OR 3 types of video (wmv,flv,mp4) TO mp4 AT ONCE,
can it be done and if so HOW ?

Comment: You can either use a global wildard `*.*` or list the individual file masks. `*.wmv *.flv` with the `DIR` command.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /B *.wmv *.flv') do ffmpeg -i "%a" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p "%~na.mp4"`

Comment: very good! thanks!

what about several mp4's to mp4? (for decreasing the size)

sorry for ignorance but how to use the DIR command inside the command?

Comment: You won't be able to read and write the same exact file name if you are working with the same file type.  So your output file either needs to go into a different output directory with the same file name or in the same directory with a different output file name.

Answer (score 0):

solved! you right!

changed some parameters, thanks a lot Stephan and Squashman

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /B *.*') do ffmpeg -i "%a" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 30 "%~nanew.mp4""
```

Comment: You have a typo of an additional trailing doublequote, in your code above.